# way to use moles for windows phone 7 projects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, moles

I'd like to use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) library to overload some Mircosoft.Pnone.Net calls (`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` for example) for my unit-tests.

I've downloaded moles installer. Installed it. Then I clicked a `Microsoft.Phone` reference and selected menu item 'Add Moles Assembley'.

And now, when I try to build my solution I got a bunch of errors like this one:

```
   Error    89  Type 'System.Net.WebRequest' exists in 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference` 

    Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll', 
    and also in  'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference 
    Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Net.dll' 
    [C:\Projects\{projName}.Tests\obj\Debug\Moles\mp\m.g.csproj]    
    C:\Projects\{projName}.Tests\m.g.cs 39886
```

Is there any way to fix this ambiguity?